# Respawn is not resetting my SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, integration-testing

I'm using [Respawn](https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn) to clean up my test database, but when this method executes:

```
public static Task ResetCheckpoint() => Checkpoint.Reset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnection"].ConnectionString);
```

This error message is shown:

> Message: System.InvalidOperationException : Invalid operation. The connection is closed.

I have already checked the value returned by  `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnection"].ConnectionString` and it is correct.

I based my integration test structure in this sample project by [Jimmy Bogard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58508/jimmy-bogard): https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityDotNetCore-Pages, more specifically, these two classes:

- https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityDotNetCore-Pages/blob/master/ContosoUniversity.IntegrationTests/IntegrationTestBase.cs
- https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityDotNetCore-Pages/blob/master/ContosoUniversity.IntegrationTests/SliceFixture.cs

Comment: The examples on the page you linked show C# using `await`. I'm guessing this is all intended for asynchronous tasks. Maybe that is your issue? Like so: `await checkpoint.Reset("MyConnectionStringName");`

Comment: The method of SliceFeature is exactly the same as my implementation: public static Task ResetCheckpoint() => _checkpoint.Reset(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

Comment: There is no await in this call

Comment: But it is async, yes?

Comment: Yes, it is async. I have already figured this out, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured this out. The issue was the connection timeout. I'm using a clone from the production database as a test database and there are many tables with a lot of rows, some with millions of registers. So I ran the commands generates by Respawn by hand, in SQL Server Management Studio, and it took 17 minutes to clear it all. For now on, I'm going to be able to write and run my tests with a clean database, without issues.

So, the lesson learned here is:

- Clear a big database before running Respawn `Reset`, or set the `CommandTimeout` property of `Checkout` class to a higher value.

I think Respawn could return a better message of what has gone wrong in the `Reset`, maybe I'll send a pull request to address this issue.

Comment: I had to add something like this:

`var cn = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
cn.ConnectTimeout = 60;
checkpoint.Reset(cn.ToString());`